# vuejs3 array length does not update appropriately

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

i am trying to build a shop and i try to add items to the cart but for some reason the cart length is wrong as i am trying to be able to add items to the cart without having duplicates in terms of items names. so when i add the same item twice it basically shows only 1 item in the cart if though i have 2.

i tried changing the the addtocart function to recognize items by there id as my items have these properties: id, name, price and quantity. i am trying to count the number of items in the cart by using foreach loop. because when i tries using the javascript array.length function it did not worked. so i am trying now with foreach loop. my code is like this:

shop.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Shop</h1>
    Items in cart: {{ cartnum }}
    <div v-for="item in Products" :key="item.id">
      {{ item.name }} {{ item.price }}$
      <button @click="storeCounter.addToCart(item)">Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
import { useCounterStore } from "../stores/counter";
import { computed } from "vue";
import Products from "../db.json";

const storeCounter = useCounterStore();

const cartnum = computed(() => storeCounter.cartnum);
</script>
```

cart.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="cart">
    <h1>Cart</h1>
    <div class="cartitems" v-for="item in storeCounter.cart" :key="item.id">
      {{ item.name }} {{ item.price }}$ {{ item.quantity }}
      <button @click="storeCounter.removeFromCart(item)">X</button>
    </div>
    <h4>total items: {{ cartnum }}</h4>
    <h4>Total Price: {{ cartSum }}</h4>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useCounterStore } from "../stores/counter";
import { computed } from "vue";

const storeCounter = useCounterStore();

const cartSum = computed(() => {
  let total = 0;
  storeCounter.cart.forEach((item) => {
    total += item.price * item.quantity;
  });
  return total;
});
const cartnum = computed(() => storeCounter.cartnum);
</script>
```

pinia file:

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useCounterStore = defineStore("counter", {
  state: () => ({
    cart: [],
  }),
  actions: {
    addToCart(item) {
      let cartItemIndex = this.cart.findIndex((x) => x.id === item.id);

      if (cartItemIndex >= 0) {
        item.quantity++;
      } else {
        this.cart.push(item);
      }
    },
    removeFromCart(id) {
      let cartItemIndex = this.cart.findIndex((x) => x === id);

      if (cartItemIndex >= 0) {
        this.cart.splice(cartItemIndex, 1);
        console.log("Removed from cart");
      }
    },
  },
  getters: {
    cartnum() {
      let total = 0;
      this.cart.forEach((item) => {
        total += item.quantity;
      });
      return total;
    },
  },
});
```

how do i fix that? thanks in advance!

Comment: `item.quantity++` - this is a mistake at least. item is not reactive. Should liekly be `let cartItem = this.cart.find(...); ... cartItem.quantity++`

Comment: @EstusFlask thx but it does not help as i still have duplicates like if i was using just .push method...

Comment: Consider updating what your current code looks like

Comment: @EstusFlask i just changed item.qauntity++ to cartItemIndex.quantity++ and i changed this.cart.findindex to just find.

Comment: Should obviously be `if (cartItem)`, and then I'd expect it to work. If the problem persists, please, provide a way to reproduce

Comment: @EstusFlask it does not work as the item shows twice which i do not want to.

Comment: You must [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77672135/edit) your question with your updated code so others can see your new attempts at solving the issue and point out what's wrong or what additional code changes you need to make.

Answer (score 0):

In the methods addToCart and removeFromCart of your store, you are never reasigning your cart state.
=> Thry reasinging this state so vue reactivity sytem will be aware that a rerender is needed :

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useCounterStore = defineStore('counter', {
  state: () => ({
    cart: [],
  }),
  actions: {
    addToCart(item) {
      const tempCart = [...this.cart];
      const cartItem = tempCart.find(({ id }) => id === item.id);

      if (cartItem) {
        cartItem.quantity++;
      } else {
        tempCart.push(item);
      }

      this.cart = tempCart;
    },
    removeFromCart(id) {
      this.cart = this.cart.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
    },
  },
  getters: {
    cartnum() {
      return this.cart.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue.quantity, 0);
    },
  },
});
```